# mysq[i].caption into editbox.text on delphi 7

Tags: delphi-7

I keep getting the full alphabet with this program when I only want the letter.
How do I get the specific letter?

```pascal
var 
  Form1: TForm1;
  mysq : array[1..26] of TPanel;

implementation

…

procedure TForm1.mySqMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  i, a: integer; 
begin  
  a := StrToInt(lab_leftn.Caption);
  
  lab_leftn.Caption := IntToStr(a - 1);

  if lab_leftn.Caption = IntToStr(0) then    
  begin     
    ShowMessage('You have lost');     
    lab_leftn.Caption := IntToStr(0);
  end;

  for i := 1 to 26 do
    ed_guessed.Text := ed_guessed.Text + mysq[i].Caption;
end;
```

Comment: The numbers each represent a letter of the English alphabet

Comment: It is not clear what "specific letter" you are looking for. Please clarify the actual issue you are having. Also, `IntToStr(0)` can be rewritten as simply `'0'`. And `if lab_leftn.Caption = IntToStr(0) then` can be simplified to `if (a-1) = 0 then` or `Dec(a); if a = 0 then`. And I would suggest using `lab_leftn.Tag` to hold the number displayed in `lab_leftn.Caption` so you can avoid `StrToInt(lab_leftn.Caption)` completely

Comment: so if I click on a button I want say letter 'A' but I get the entire alphabet. The letter I click on is supposed to be put into an editbox but it puts the entire alphabet in. I would love to know how to only get the letter I have selected to be put in.

Comment: You have not shown any button click handler yet. Do you mean the `OnKey(Down|up)` handler you have shown? Do you want to display the key that is being pressed? Your handler is running a loop that appends 26 `TPanel` captions to `ed_guessed`. Is that what you are referring to? I'm assuming those panels are labeled `A`, `B`, `C`, etc? Have you tried simply removing that loop? If this is not what you are referring to, then you need to [edit] your question to clarify the issue better, preferably with an actual example of what you are expecting, and what you are actually getting instead.

Comment: exactly what I'm referring to. Sorry about the communication error. When the panel "button" is clicked, it sends its caption into the edit box. The captions are labelled A to Z in respect to 1 to 26, for each letter. It's supposed to give me the specific panel "button" 's caption alone but it gives me all of the captions at once. I have tried removing the loop and it gives me an access error on that line. Again, sorry about the bad communication.

Comment: presumably you have assigned this `mySqMouseDown` handler to all 26 panels. If so, then use the `Sender` parameter to know which panel is being clicked, eg: `ed_guessed.Text := ed_guessed.Text + TPanel(Sender).Caption;` No loop needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming mySqMouseDown has been assigned to all TPanel OnMouseDown event, then the correct code is this one:

```
procedure TForm1.mySqMouseDown(
    Sender : TObject; 
    Button : TMouseButton;
    Shift  : TShiftState; 
    X, Y   : Integer);
var
  i, a: integer; 
begin  
  a := StrToInt(lab_leftn.Caption);
  lab_leftn.Caption := IntToStr(a - 1);
  if lab_leftn.Caption = IntToStr(0) then begin     
    ShowMessage('You have lost');     
    lab_leftn.Caption := IntToStr(0);
  end;

  ed_guessed.Text := (Sender as TPanel).Caption;
end;
```